# MySQL: SELECT from another server

Tags: mysql, networking, data-transfer

I'm afraid that I already know the answer to my question, but I'll ask it anyway:

When there are two MySQL DB servers, can I access data that is stored on the other server?

In other words: Can I somehow do this:

```
INSERT INTO table (x, y, z)
   SELECT x, y, x+y
      FROM [otherserver].[database].[table]
```

Is the answer really as short as "No"?

Comment: This article on ["Running MySQL queries on multiple servers"](http://www.linux.com/feature/52390) sounds like it explains how to do what you want to do. The link is currently dead, so here is the content [from archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20090302102331/http://www.linux.com/feature/52390?):

Comment: Thought about something like that for a moment, but I can't do it that way, because we use replication for... well... replication - between other servers. :)

Comment: Use federated table. Refer this: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set up federated tables in MySQL to accomplish what you're trying to do. There are some limitations.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/federated-storage-engine.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/federated-usagenotes.html

Comment: This looks really interesting :)

Comment: My recommendation: never ever consider touching federeated tables.
They seem like unmaintained for years, instable stuff, horrible to maintain and totally unoptimized.
An unlimited amount of troubles ahead

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `remote_table`(
  `foo` VARCHAR(100),
  UNIQUE KEY(`foo`(30))
) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://thedomain.com:3306/remotedbname/remotetablename';
```

Then query it like any other table with SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this. Let's say you're in the target box (where you want to copy the tables TO):

```
-bash$ mysqldump -u user -p password -h remote_host --databases \
db_name --tables table1 table2 table3 | mysql -u user -p password \
-D local_db_name
```

This will pull the data from the remote host with mysqldump and insert it into your local host.

Comment: Obviously you can do that, but the whole point is to access data that lives on another server, not to (occasionally) copy over the data.