# How to access a database in a different server?

Tags: mysql

Today I have 2 databases (DB_A and DB_B) in the same server (SERVER_1). When I need to access tables from one to the other - in a trigger, for example - all I need to do is to refer to the desired table like this:

```
-- Code in DB_A accessing DB_B
...
select * from DB_B.TableInB
...
```

But the code above will fail if I move DB_B from SERVER_1 to SERVER_2.

In MS-SQL we can use a linked server, and simply use **SERVER_2.DB_B.Schema.TableInB**, but I can not find anything similar in MySQL.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508100/mysql-select-from-another-server). Now, I'm no expert at all with federated tables, but that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out ChrisForrence is right: [federated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508100/mysql-select-from-another-server), although limited, are the way to go to link different servers.

Answer (score -1):

Use OPENROWSET

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'dsn=mydsn;uid=myid;pwd=mypwd;',
'SELECT * FROM TableInB')
```