# Select Insert Query by mentioning all columns across databases

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

I am working on redesigning of a legacy db and I have set new names to columns of old db. So, for instance, if `olddb.oldtable` under `dbold` has column `descr`, I have set it as `description` in new `newdb.netable` for column.

How can I mention individual columns in my query?

I am using MYSQL

*Update*: Both Databases are on different IP Addresses and I am using Navicat to transfer data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mention'? I hope you kept track of all those changes.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Qs updated.

Comment: Any luck with this? If you find a solution please post it because I am interested in it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all columns at once without the need to mention the names using this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (SELECT * FROM oldtable);
```

It will make an 1x1 match independently of column names.

If types don't match then will insert default values (not checked for all the type combination).

Note that column number must be the same on both tables otherwise an error like this will occur:

```
 #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: Do remember column names are different in both db tables

Comment: speaking of type matches, if a column is `int` and other is `tinyint`, it will not work?

Comment: It will work but default value will be 0. It will work even if one column is timestamp and the other is int (but I haven't checked for all the combinations).

Comment: I am getting error `Error : Table 'olddb.table' doesn't exist`. I am trying this in my Db Client(Navicat pro)

Comment: Hm, 'table' is a reserved word for MySQL. Try with backticks.

Comment: Well , real query is: `INSERT INTO homestead.categories (SELECT * FROM spec.cs_cats);`

Comment: I just checked it using MySQL 5 using 2 different tables from 2 different databases and it works normally. Check the table names.

Comment: By default any Db client selects a single connection. I am mentioning db name as `spec `.categories, where `spec` is Db name. What am I doing wrong? my DB client is not recognizing old Db

Comment: Both Databases are on different IP Addresses and I am using Navicat to transfer data.

Comment: Oh, that explains it. I suggest you to make a new question for this specific problem.

Comment: I think that somehow you have to use different connection names.

Comment: I don't know if something like this exists but try: INSERT INTO server1_connection.homestead.categories (SELECT * FROM server2_connection.spec.cs_cats);

Comment: May be you find these useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508100/mysql-select-from-another-server, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html, http://archive09.linux.com/feature/52390

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (col1, col2, ..., )
SELECT col1, col2, ..., FROM oldtable
```

By trying the above query you can insert the specific column. So for example if your newtable has a column as description and old table as descr then you can mention it like:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (col1, col2, `description`,  ..., )
SELECT col1, col2, `descr` ,..., FROM oldtable
```

Also if the table column list is large and you want to copy all the columns and its data then you can simply use the wildcard charater `*` as:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```