# Get data from two different MYSQL DATABASE exist on two different server using JOIN query

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I have two database on two different server. I need to get data from both server using JOIN query at same time. There is constraint on both database table.

## FIRST DATABASE

> There is a table TABLE1 of user and a entity **userid** exist in table.

## SECOND DATABASE

> There is another table TABLE2 of user calling details and having **userid** comman of TABLE1.

Now i need to get calling detail of all user according to their userid using join query.

Please help me how i can connect remote database at same time.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: In addition to ^. What MySQL version(s)? Is there a reason its architected to be on different servres?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: SELECT from another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508100/mysql-select-from-another-server)